# Find duplicate and merge record into single datatable c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, sum

I am able to find the duplicates out of DataTable rows. Like following:

```
var groups = table.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => new
        {
            c1 = r.Field<String>("Version"),
        });
        var tblDuplicates = groups
            .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(grp => grp)
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Now, I want to merge all the duplicate records in to single and sum it's Value column value.

Pretty much like following:

DataTable with Duplicates:

```
Version   Value  
1  2

2  2

2  1

1  3

2  1

3  2
```

DataTable with no duplicates and Value summed.:

```
Version   Value  
1  5

2  4

3  2
```

I am aware about this link which does this with the help of reflection. 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1570562.aspx/1

Anyother way to do it?

Edit:
However, if I have more than two columns, like five columns and I still want to do the sum on Value column and also need other columns data in resulatant summed datatable. How to do it? Here I get the Version and Value in my result DataTable. I want other columns with values also. Like following:

Version col1 col2   Value

```
1  A A 2

2  B B 2

2  B B 1

1  A A 3

2  B B 1

3  C C 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Version"))
            .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = table.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = new object[]
                        {
                            g.Key, 
                            g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Value"))
                        };
                    return row;
                }).CopyToDataTable();
```

**Edit:**

If you want to keep other field, try below:

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => new
                {
                     Version = r.Field<String>("Version"),
                     Col1 =  r.Field<String>("Col1"),
                     Col2 =  r.Field<String>("Col2")
                })
            .Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = g.First();
                    row.SetField("Value", g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Value")));
                    return row;
                }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Should't it be `g.Sum(x=>x.Value)` instead of `g.Count`?

Comment: Right @Spontifixus. I modified it to that and it is working. However, if I have more than two columns, like five columns and I still want to do the sum on Value column and also need other columns data in resulatant summed datatable. How to do it? Here I get the Version and Value in my result DataTable. I want other columns with values also.

Comment: @JayNanavati: edit your question, I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @CuongLe then that deserves an upvote and the removal of my own answer  - yours is more accurate... ;)

Comment: Hi I am having a dataset which comes from my database then how can I achieve as per you did

Comment: +1 for keeping the whole row without typing every column name into a new anonymous type. Thanks!